React native upgrade
f I have an AndroidManifest.xml without a package declaration, I encounter an issue where the build fails.
Where:
Script 'xxxx@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 401

What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Process 'command 'node'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
However, when I add the package declaration, the configuration passes, but the execution fails with the following error.
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.

Incorrect package="xxxx" found in source AndroidManifest.xml: Cxxxxmobile\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.
Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported.
Recommendation: remove package="xxxx" from the source AndroidManifest.xml: xxxmobile\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml.

Also,When I run npx react-native config, I encounter the following error: 'Failed to build the app: No package name found. We couldn't parse the namespace from either your build.gradle[.kts] file or your package in the AndroidManifest.xml.' This happens in the android/build.gradle and android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml files. However, when I add the package name, the error disappears, and the operation completes successfully. What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it?
build.gradle
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
        kotlinVersion = "1.9.22"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15')
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin")
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"

update to 0.74.5 from 0.71.10 using React Native Upgrade Helper
androidManifest
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/> 

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
      android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
    >
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon" android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color" android:resource="@color/colorAccent" />
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE"/>

        </intent-filter>
          <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
              <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
              <data android:scheme="xxx" />
          </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
     <queries>
         <intent>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
           <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
         </intent>
       </queries>
</manifest>


Care to share the following details: 1. Your build.gradle files 2. Your RN version 3. Your AndroidManifest file ?
